# Calculate difference by group

Tags: r, difference

I would like to calculate the distance by group. Three classes in the data frame.

```
Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species 
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  versicolor
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa 
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  virginica
```

I have also calculated the row sum of each class

```
rsums = aggregate(iris$rsum, by=list(Class=iris$Species), FUN=sum)
```

and the outcome come is like

```
      Class Centroid
1     setosa   1521.3
2 versicolor   2143.8
3  virginica   2571.0
```

So I need to subtract sum of each group to each row value of same group, to get the absolute difference, for example given below.

```
            Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species 
    1          5.1-1521.3  3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
    2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
    3          4.7-2143.8  3.2          1.3         0.2  versicolor
    4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
    5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa 
    6          5.4-2571.0  3.9          1.7         0.4  virginica
```

Comment: How did you compute the `rsum` column in the `iris` data set?

Comment: `iris$rsum = rowSums(iris[,-5])`

Comment: So, you want to subtract the row sum for the __group__ (`rsums`) from the row sum for a __row__ (each `rsum`)?

Comment: I think it is unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It think your question is a bit unclear. But does

```
iris$rsum <- rowSums(iris[,-5])
rsums <- aggregate(iris$rsum, by=list(Class=iris$Species), FUN=sum)
iris[,-(5:6)] <- iris[,-(5:6)] - rsums$x[iris$Species]
head(iris)
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species rsum
#1      -1516.2     -1517.8      -1519.9     -1521.1  setosa 30.6
#2      -1516.4     -1518.3      -1519.9     -1521.1  setosa 28.5
#3      -1516.6     -1518.1      -1520.0     -1521.1  setosa 28.2
#4      -1516.7     -1518.2      -1519.8     -1521.1  setosa 28.2
#5      -1516.3     -1517.7      -1519.9     -1521.1  setosa 30.6
#6      -1515.9     -1517.4      -1519.6     -1520.9  setosa 34.2
```

do what you want?

This utilizes the fact that `iris$Species` is a factor together with R's reuse rules when subtracting.